# Isotope (JS) not working

Tags: jquery-isotope

Looking to implement some kind of filtering so have started to look at Isotope and getting nowhere fast. I've literally copied the HTML, CSS and JS from the Codepen part of the site but cannot get the JS/Jquery functionality at all. Here's the original CodePen: https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/Ehgij

And here is my effort. I'm running this on Django, and yes, my static files are loading(!) not that it matters as the JS is pointing to the CDN online.

Everything loads fine EXCEPT the JS functionality so presumably I'm doing something very silly with the script...

```
{% load static %}


    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/isotope-docs.css' %}">
    </head>

    <script>
    // external js: isotope.pkgd.js

    // init Isotope
    var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
      itemSelector: '.element-item',
      layoutMode: 'fitRows'
    });
    // filter functions
    var filterFns = {
      // show if number is greater than 50
      numberGreaterThan50: function() {
        var number = $(this).find('.number').text();
        return parseInt( number, 10 ) > 50;
      },
      // show if name ends with -ium
      ium: function() {
        var name = $(this).find('.name').text();
        return name.match( /ium$/ );
      }
    };
    // bind filter button click
    $('.filters-button-group').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
      var filterValue = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
      // use filterFn if matches value
      filterValue = filterFns[ filterValue ] || filterValue;
      $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
    });
    // change is-checked class on buttons
    $('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
      var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
      $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function() {
        $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
        $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
      });
    });

    </script>
    <div class="big-demo go-wide" data-js="sorting-demo">

      <div class="button-group sort-by-button-group js-radio-button-group">
        <button class="button is-checked" data-sort-by="original-order">original order</button>
        <button class="button" data-sort-by="name">name</button>
        <button class="button" data-sort-by="symbol">symbol</button>
        <button class="button" data-sort-by="number">number</button>
        <button class="button" data-sort-by="weight">weight</button>
        <button class="button" data-sort-by="category">category</button>
      </div>


      <div class="grid">
          <div class="element-item transition metal " data-category="transition">
            <h5 class="name">Mercury</h5>
            <p class="symbol">Hg</p>
            <p class="number">80</p>
            <p class="weight">200.59</p>
          </div>
          <div class="element-item metalloid " data-category="metalloid">
            <h5 class="name">Tellurium</h5>
            <p class="symbol">Te</p>
            <p class="number">52</p>
            <p class="weight">127.6</p>
          </div>
          <div class="element-item post-transition metal " data-category="post-transition">
            <h5 class="name">Bismuth</h5>
            <p class="symbol">Bi</p>
            <p class="number">83</p>
            <p class="weight">208.980</p>
          </div>
          <div class="element-item post-transition metal " data-category="post-transition">
            <h5 class="name">Lead</h5>
            <p class="symbol">Pb</p>
            <p class="number">82</p>
            <p class="weight">207.2</p>
          </div>
          <div class="element-item transition metal " data-category="transition">
            <h5 class="name">Gold</h5>
            <p class="symbol">Au</p>
            <p class="number">79</p>
            <p class="weight">196.967</p>
          </div>
          <div class="element-item alkali metal " data-category="alkali">
            <h5 class="name">Potassium</h5>
            <p class="symbol">K</p>
            <p class="number">19</p>
            <p class="weight">39.0983</p>
          </div>
          <div class="element-item alkali metal " data-category="alkali">
            <h5 class="name">Sodium</h5>
            <p class="symbol">Na</p>
            <p class="number">11</p>
            <p class="weight">22.99</p>
          </div>
          <div class="element-item transition metal " data-category="transition">
            <h5 class="name">Cadmium</h5>
            <p class="symbol">Cd</p>
            <p class="number">48</p>
            <p class="weight">112.411</p>
          </div>
          <div class="element-item alkaline-earth metal " data-category="alkaline-earth">
            <h5 class="name">Calcium</h5>
            <p class="symbol">Ca</p>
            <p class="number">20</p>
            <p class="weight">40.078</p>
          </div>
          <div class="element-item transition metal " data-category="transition">
            <h5 class="name">Rhenium</h5>
            <p class="symbol">Re</p>
            <p class="number">75</p>
            <p class="weight">186.207</p>
          </div>
          <div class="element-item post-transition metal " data-category="post-transition">
            <h5 class="name">Thallium</h5>
            <p class="symbol">Tl</p>
            <p class="number">81</p>
            <p class="weight">204.383</p>
          </div>
          <div class="element-item metalloid " data-category="metalloid">
            <h5 class="name">Antimony</h5>
            <p class="symbol">Sb</p>
            <p class="number">51</p>
            <p class="weight">121.76</p>
          </div>
          <div class="element-item transition metal " data-category="transition">
            <h5 class="name">Cobalt</h5>
            <p class="symbol">Co</p>
            <p class="number">27</p>
            <p class="weight">58.933</p>
          </div>
          <div class="element-item lanthanoid metal inner-transition " data-category="lanthanoid">
            <h5 class="name">Ytterbium</h5>
            <p class="symbol">Yb</p>
            <p class="number">70</p>
            <p class="weight">173.054</p>
          </div>
          <div class="element-item noble-gas nonmetal " data-category="noble-gas">
            <h5 class="name">Argon</h5>
            <p class="symbol">Ar</p>
            <p class="number">18</p>
            <p class="weight">39.948</p>
          </div>
          <div class="element-item diatomic nonmetal " data-category="diatomic">
            <h5 class="name">Nitrogen</h5>
            <p class="symbol">N</p>
            <p class="number">7</p>
            <p class="weight">14.007</p>
          </div>
          <div class="element-item actinoid metal inner-transition " data-category="actinoid">
            <h5 class="name">Uranium</h5>
            <p class="symbol">U</p>
            <p class="number">92</p>
            <p class="weight">238.029</p>
          </div>
          <div class="element-item actinoid metal inner-transition " data-category="actinoid">
            <h5 class="name">Plutonium</h5>
            <p class="symbol">Pu</p>
            <p class="number">94</p>
            <p class="weight">(244)</p>
          </div>
      </div>
```

*edit for the avoidance of doubt, when I say "nothing happens" I mean, literally nothing happens when you click on the filters. No errors in the firefox dev console either.

Comment: "Not working" is not a technical term or description.

Comment: When you click a filter, it is supposed to filter the displaying objects. Nothing happens on click, nothing. In the developer console, there is no error either.

Comment: Put that in your question, not the comments.

Comment: Fixed, thanks anyway. Dumb question I guess.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I went a walk, done some shopping, came back, and had a very miniscule brainwave - put the script *at the bottom* of body, and now it works. Huh.